# How to use Glide

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to implement glide in my game but I don't know how.
I know that the Glide format is:

`Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.image).into(imageView);`

But I don't understand how to implement it in my game.class

Game.class:

```
public class Game extends SurfaceView {

    Player player;
    Paint paint;
    Bitmap image_player;

    public Game(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        paint = new Paint();
        image_player = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player);
        player = new Player(this, image_player);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);

        player.onDraw(canvas);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Player.Class:

```
public class Player {

    private Game game;
    private Bitmap player;
    Paint paint;

    int x, y, start = 0, width, height, currentFrame = 0,Horizontal = 1, Vertical = 8, frameLengthInMilliseconds = 150, cantFrames = 8;
    long fps, timeThisFrame, lastFrameChangeTime = 0;

    public Player(Game juego, Bitmap player){

        this.game = game;
        this.player = player;
        this.width = player.getWidth() / Vertical;
        this.height = player.getHeight() / Horizontal;

        paint = new Paint();
    }

    private void update() {

        long startFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (startFrame > lastFrameChangeTime + frameLengthInMilliseconds) {
            lastFrameChangeTime = startFrame;
            currentFrame++;
            if (currentFrame >= cantFrames) {

                currentFrame = 0;
            }
        }

        long startFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        timeThisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis() - startFrameTime;
        if (timeThisFrame >= 1) {
            fps = 1000 / timeThisFrame;
        }
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        update();

        int srcX = currentFrame * width;
        int srcY = height * start;

        x = canvas.getWidth()/2;
        y = canvas.getHeight()/2;

        Rect src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + width, srcY + height);
        Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);

        canvas.drawBitmap(player, src, dst, null);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.example.agusv.MyProject.Game
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

glide is used to set the image on an `ImageView`

you need to define an image view in your layout

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView">
</ImageView>
```

and then you can set an image on this image view using glide:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.image).into(imageView);
```

there's a more detailed explanation on [this page](http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/glide-image-loading-library-for-android-tutorial/)